# Update a git branch?

Tags: git, branch

In the following situation, how can I "update" the simon_master branch to include all the merged changes from the rene_master branch? My ideal scenario would be to have the simon_master branch just branch out from the rene_master again after the most recent commit shown. What would you do?

Cheers,

S
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like a fast-forward merge so you should have no problem simply merging the `Rene_Master` branch  into the `simon_master` branch.

In the terminal I'd do:

```
> git checkout simon_master
> git merge Rene_Master
```

Comment: Doing a merge is the only sane thing to do at this point because you've pushed the commits in simon_master. If you hadn't pushed any commits from simon_master then you could do `git rebase Rene_Master` while on your branch.